# Tuple seen as Product, compiler rejects reference to element

Tags: scala

Constructing phoneVector:

```
  val phoneVector = (
    for (i <- 1 until 20) yield {
      val p = killNS(r.get("Phone %d - Value" format(i)))
      val t = killNS(r.get("Phone %d - Type" format(i)))
        if (p == None) None
        else
          if (t == None) (p,"Main") else (p,t)
    }
  ).filter(_ != None)
```

Consider this very simple snippet:

```
  for (pTuple <- phoneVector) {
    println(pTuple.getClass.getName)
    println(pTuple)
    //val pKey = pTuple._1.replaceAll("[^\\d]","")
    associate() // stub prints "associate"
  }
```

When I run it, I see output like this:

```
scala.Tuple2
((609) 954-3815,Mobile)
associate
```

When I uncomment the line with `replaceAll()`, compile fails:

```
....scala:57: value _1 is not a member of Product with Serializable
[error]         val pKey = pTuple._1.replaceAll("[^\\d]","")
[error]                           ^
```

Why does it not recognize `pTuple` as a `Tuple2` and treat it only as `Product`

Comment: How are you construction `phoneVector`?

Comment: I've added the preceding code.  I assume I should seek a way to make the type Tuple explicit earlier.  Similar consideration may apply to killDNS which can currently return String or None.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By changing the construction of phoneVector, as wrick's question implied, I've been able to eliminate the match/case stuff because Tuple is assured.  Not thrilled by it, but Change is Hard, and Scala seems cool.

Now, it's still possible to slip a None value into either of the Tuple values.  My match/case does not check for that, and I suspect that could lead to a runtime error in the replaceAll call.  How is that allowed?

```
  def killNS (s:Option[_]) = {
    (s match {
      case _:Some[_] => s.get
      case _ => None
    }) match {
      case None => None
      case "" => None
      case s => s
    }
  }

  val phoneVector = (
    for (i <- 1 until 20) yield {
      val p = killNS(r.get("Phone %d - Value" format(i)))
      val t = killNS(r.get("Phone %d - Type" format(i)))
      if (t == None) (p,"Main") else (p,t)
    }
  ).filter(_._1 != None)
  println(phoneVector)
  println(name)
  println
  // Create the Neo4j nodes:
  for (pTuple <- phoneVector) {
    val pPhone = pTuple._1 match { case p:String => p }
    val pType = pTuple._2
    val pKey = pPhone.replaceAll(",.*","").replaceAll("[^\\d]","")
    associate(Map("target"->Map("label"->"Phone","key"->pKey,
                                                 "dial"->pPhone),
                  "relation"->Map("label"->"IS_AT","key"->pType),
                  "source"->Map("label"->"Person","name"->name)
                 )
             )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, this compiles and produces the desired result.  But it's too verbose.  Can someone please demonstrate a more concise solution for dealing with this typesafe stuff?

```
  for (pTuple <- phoneVector) {
    println(pTuple.getClass.getName)
    println(pTuple)
    val pPhone = pTuple match {
      case t:Tuple2[_,_] => t._1
      case _ => None
    }
    val pKey = pPhone match {
      case s:String => s.replaceAll("[^\\d]","")
      case _ => None
    }
    println(pKey)
    associate()
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
  for (pTuple <- phoneVector) {
    val pPhone = pTuple match {
      case (key, value) => key
      case _ => None
    }
    val pKey = pPhone match {
      case s:String => s.replaceAll("[^\\d]","")
      case _ => None
    }
    println(pKey)
    associate()
  }
```

Or simply `phoneVector.map(_._1.replaceAll("[^\\d]",""))`

Comment: I tried to avoid posting too much code, but I guess the problem is less about the example and more about by clumsiness with the idioms.  At this phase of the processing, I know the tuples are pairs of strings and I just need to pass them on to associate() with some other data.  But I haven't clued the compiler in and it is trying to protect me.  I'll consider a variant of the .map() approach.